# shell script as cron job

Tags: shell, cron

Several people have had this problem, but none of the fixes mentioned around the net have worked for me.

I have a simple shell script that copies log files from a few directories, and puts them in one single directory on a remote machine. The script works fine.

I then create a cronjob, which doesnt seem to execute. My crontab looks like:

```
1 * * * * /bin/bash /home/user/myscripts/getlogs.sh > /tmp/cronscript.out 2>&1
```

`/var/log/cron` shows this every minute 
`Aug 20 17:02:01 hostname crond[2614]: (root) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/root)`

so it cron job executes, but it doesnt seem to run the shell script.

Comment: Is the file `/tmp/cronscript.out` created?  If so, what does it contain?  If not, then you need to worry about whether `cron` knows it is supposed to run the script (check `crontab -l`).  If the file exists, then you need to see what it contains.  Consider adding `-x` as an extra argument between `bash` and `/home`.

Comment: the file isnt created: cannot open `/tmp/cronscript.out' for reading: No such file or directory.                                               Also, crontab -l shows                                                SHELL=/bin/bash                                                       What does -x do?
1 * * * *  /home/user/myscripts/getlogs.sh >> /tmp/cronscript.out 2>&1

Comment: OK; then it looks to me as though `cron` is not trying to run the job, or is failing utterly to run it.  Look at the cron log for errors.  Look at other cron commands.  I don't trust I/O redirection on the command line inside `cron` entries; I run a script directly (which has the correct shebang at the top), and it handles I/O redirection for itself.  That may work for you.  Have you set up cron jobs before?  If so, what's different about this one compared to those you've done before?

Comment: Please go through the debugging steps in the [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info). Your particular problem is #2, incorrect timespec.

Comment: @thatotherguy: The timespec isn't *incorrect*, but it may not be what the OP intended. It will run once an hour at 1 minute past the hour.

Comment: @KeithThompson Then it's incorrect. It's just not invalid.

Comment: @thatotherguy: Depends on what the OP wants. (Words is hard.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Can you highlight the ambiguity? I'm not saying you're wrong, but I can't seem to find any interpretation that suggests anything other than an expectation that the job should run every minute.

Comment: @thatotherguy the 1 minute increment OP mentions is cron's frequency of reports to its log file. OP doesn't state any schedule time other than the 1 minute after the hour that the job is configured for.

Comment: What does the getlogs.sh contain?